# Form validation script before submission

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

There is a form, where on submission the new page is opened, only in case if validation is ok. However, the window is opened in every case, and I guess that validation isnt working, while it is supposed to...
I would appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function overallcheck() {
            if (!checkjob() || !checkEmail() || !Checkname()) {
                writeTo("problemArea", "Error messages area");
                return false;
            }
            if (!Checkname()) {
                writeTo("problemArea", "Please inser a valid name");
                return false;
            }
            if (!checkEmail()) {
                writeTo("problemArea", "Please inser a valid email");
                return false;
            }
            if (!checkjob()) {
                writeTo("problemArea", "Please inser your job");
                return false;
            }
            elsereturn true;
        }

        function Checkname() {
            clearElement("problemArea");
            var fullname = document.forms['form'].fullname.value;
            if (fullname.length == 0 || !isNaN(fullname))
                return false;
        }

        function checkEmail() {
            clearElement("problemArea");
            var mail = document.forms['form'].Email.value;
            if (mail == '' || mail.indexOf('@') == -1 || mail.indexOf('.') == -1)
                return false;
        }
        }

        function checkjob() {
            clearElement("problemArea");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (document.forms['form'].job[i].checked) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

         //-->
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form onsubmit=( "return overallcheck();") action="another.html" id=form target="_blank" method="GET">
        <table>

            <button type="submit" onclick="">submit</button>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain `onsubmit=("return overallcheck();")` and `elsereturn true;` ?

Comment: Overallcheck checks all forms, if form is completed correctly, then it returns  true. The new page should be opened only if overacheck is true, otherwise, there will be an error message

Comment: I have tried many ways, I saw online. Return fuction() is one of it. The logic however is to call overallcheck before the action

Answer (score 0):

Well... That's invalid JavaScript. As [NewToJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4169803/newtojs) noted in his comment, `elsereturn true;` is not correct.

You need to use:

```
else {
    return true;
}
```

Also, this (`onsubmit=( "return overallcheck();")`) won't work. You need to do this:

```
<form onsubmit="return overallcheck();" action="another.html" id="form" target="_blank" method="GET">
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the above to the word...but still the new page opens anyway

Comment: @MayDay use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the form submitting.